# What would cause & in URLS to automatically be converted to &amp;?

Tags: php

Im a little stuck. I developed a script and for some reason it is converting `&` in URLs to `&amp;` automatically.

This is the line that is causing the issue:

```
$accessToken = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=' . APPID . '&redirect_uri=' . APPURL . 'callback.php&client_secret=' . APISECRET . '&code=' . $_REQUEST['code']);
```

And this is what the error report is returning:

```
[20-Jul-2010 15:47:35] PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=xxxxxxx&amp;redirect_uri=http://apps.facebook.com/xxxxx/callback.php&amp;client_secret=xxxxxx&amp;code=) [<a href='function.file-get-contents'>function.file-get-contents</a>]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request
```

in /home/pk1no/public_html/video/callback.php on line 8

The funny thing is the same script works on my Joyent dedicated, but not on my HostGator dedicated. I'm a little baffled by it.

Comment: I am certain it's those &amp; characters that are causing it because when I put the request in the browser with the amps I get "missing redirect" (which is after the first &amp;). If I change the &amp; to & it works.

Answer (score 2):

Might it be that the warning message is getting munged, not before the call to `file_get_contents`, and that there's some other problem?

Comment: This would be my suspicion. Note the `<a>` HTML tags - it would appear the warning message was intended to be echoed rather than going into a text-only log.

Comment: The error message is converting & to &amp; so that it can be displayed correctly in the browser. Your file_get_contents calls really is using & correctly. Something else is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Is allow_url_fopen enabled on your machine? Otherwise you cannot open files via URL.

You could also try to wrap the URL with urlencode().

Comment: Yes it is on. I tried with urlencode(). Let me see if the log file produces a different error when using that.

Comment: urlencode would not be good - it would make sure that it is using &amp; which is not good.

Comment: urlencode doesn't turn & to &amp; you're thinking of htmlentities.

Answer (score 0):

It's only the error message which has got HTML entities in so that it is presented correctly in your browser.

You're not building your URL correctly, most likely rendering it unparsable by the URL fopen wrappers. Use [urlencode](http://php.net/urlencode) to wrap anything which might contain some non URL-safe characters...

```
$url='https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token'.
    '?client_id=' . urlencode(APPID) .
    '&redirect_uri=' . urlencode(APPURL) . 'callback.php'.
    '&client_secret=' . urlencode(APISECRET) . 
    '&code=' . urlencode($_REQUEST['code']);

$accessToken = file_get_contents($url);
```